# Aruco marker detection with 360 camera?

Tags: python, opencv, 360-virtual-reality, aruco

recently I have been playing with the 360 fly HD camera and wondering if Aruco Marker can be detected during real time. The first thing come to my mind is to convert the fisheye image into perspective image first and then perform the detection on the perspective image(I am gonna try it and will update my result here later).

1. [Converting a fisheye image into a panoramic, spherical or perspective projection](http://paulbourke.net/dome/fish2/)
2. [Hugin HowTo: Convert 360 Image to Cropped Flat Panoramic Image](http://lists.theta360.guide/t/hugin-howto-convert-360-image-to-cropped-flat-panoramic-image/1271)

I am not an expert in this field. Has anyone done this before? Is this something can be achieved by calibrating the camera differently such as correcting the camera matrix and distortion coefficient matrix?

If I am heading to the wrong direction, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a better understanding during the process.

First, I want to say that 360(fisheye, spherical, however you call it) image is NOT distorted. I was so tricked by my intuition and thought that the image was distorted based on what it looks like. NO it is not distorted. Please read [enter link description here](http://paulbourke.net/dome/fish2/) for more information.

Next, I have tried both 360 fly cameras and neither works. Every time I tried to access the camera with opencv, it automatically powers off and switch to storage mode. I guess the 360 dev team purposely implements this switching function to prevent "hacking" of their products. But, I've seen people successfully hacked the 360 fly, it's definitely workable.

At last, I was able to detect Aruco with Ricoh theta V(theta S should also work). It's so developer friendly and I was able to make it run in my first attempt. You just have to select the right camera and let the code run. The only problem is the range, which is expected(about 6ft) and Ricoh camera is kind of expensive($499).

[click here to view succesful detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7YRz.jpg)